# Linkedin: image not showing up after sharing via REST Api

Tags: image, share, linkedin-api

I shared a post from an application but the image doesn't show up in the update. I realise this question is asked a couple of times already and I checked all the info I could find here, to no avail.

I checked content type, which is correct.
I checked the url, which works.
I checked the ssl certificate which seems to be fine.

The image in question is: `https://soworker.com/files/images/608-3XZcFrnujD_LN.JPG`

The share is being made using the REST Api and the share itself gives a success message.

How can I debug why the image is not showing up? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) ,it will be useful to raise your content quality

Comment: @willie not sure what you mean?

Comment: For me, LinkedIn Sharing was not working because we enforced TLS1.3 lowering the version solved it.
(Likely not your issue back then, just cross-post it since I came to this post because of a problem with LinkedIn not Scraping certain SSL certificates)

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue. When I post this url via the API - https://blog.calevans.com/2016/05/16/postcards-life-010/ - it will not show the image.

However, when I post this one - http://voicesoftheelephpant.com/2016/05/17/interview-amanda-folson/ - it works.

Since they both sit on the same server and are both running the same software, my current theory is that LinkedIn can't read images from secure servers. Alternatively, however, less likely, it may be that they won't read from sites using Let's Encrypt images.

UPDATE: It seems to be Let's Encrypt. The podcast is also available encrypted but not using a Let's Encrypt cert because Apple won't read them. I posted a second update using the https:// version and it worked.

So it LOOKS like LinkedIn doesn't like Let's Encrypt.

HTH,
=C=

Comment: Hmm... interesting... Could be the issue indeed. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently LinkedIn didn't like Lets Encrypt certificates. The problems is completely resolved now though and I don't think this will be a certificate issue anymore.